# I need clarification using width and min-width when defined as percentages

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand the discrepancy between width and min-width given to a container when their values are defined as percentages.
Consider the example below.
I begin by defining a container by giving it a width equal to 50% of the body width and a min-width of 25%. However, when resizing the browser it doesn't shrink to the minimum width I defined. It's only when the min-width is given a value of either ems, rems or pixels does it work as intended and the container shrinks to the min-width defined. Could anyone please shed some light as to why it behaves like this? To be more specific, as to why setting min-width using percentages lower than the defined width yield no results? Thankyou

```
  <style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
  }
  .container {
    width: 30%;
    min-width: 160px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: beige;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  nav > ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  nav li {
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 0.3rem;
  }
</style>
 <body>
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>New Testament</li>
      <li>Old Testament</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: 25% is **always** smaller than 50% so the width is always bigger than the min-width. setting min-width is useless is such case

Comment: Thankyou for your response as my error just dawned on me.

Comment: Would like to take a moment to explain the logic behind this: 
When the width property of a container is defined using a percentage the container will retain its width ratio as the browser width is resized. Setting a min-width prevents the container from shrinking past a certain limit but cannot override the minimum width a container can shrink. For this very reason percentages cannot be used when defining both width and min-width properties.

Comment: you are overcomplicating a simple math equation ... 25 < 50 --> this is a fact so if you set min-width:25% and width:50% the width is all the time bigger than the min-width

Comment: This is true and it stemmed from not quite grasping the min-width property as to what it entails. Now that I do I wanted to elaborate on my findings as the MDN documents could be somewhat vague at times.